# C++ How to pass int argument into string macro?

Tags: c++, macros

I declared a macro as follow:

```
#define PIECE_TAG(point,cell)       "<Piece NumberOfPoints=\"" STRING(point) "\" NumberOfCells=\"" STRING(cell) "\">"
```

with `#define STRING(str) #str`

And use it as:

```
_out << TAB << TAB << PIECE_TAG(pointsOfMesh.size() , elemsOfMesh.size() ) << ENTER;
```

but it return a string:

```
<Piece NumberOfPoints="pointsOfMesh.size()" NumberOfCells="elemsOfMesh.size()">
```

how i  can convert an integer value to string in macro of C++?
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Why not use a function that returns a string? Macros aren't encouraged in C++.

Comment: Macros have no notion of variables built into it, so unless you pass in a integer literal, there is no way to do that

Comment: Macros no longer exist once compilation is finished. That's why they are macros. So it is quite impossible for a macro to use a value not known until run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Macros interpret strings, not C++ code.

Throw out the macro and write code.

```
std::string piece_tag( std::size_t point, std::size_t cell ) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss<<"<Piece NumberOfPoints=\"" << point << "\" NumberOfCells=\"" <<cell << "\">";
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: thank your replied!
I  had writen it as function before.
I just find the way to use macro.